# How to avoid having a pipeline of functions?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, functional-programming, pipeline

I am currently in the process of writing code that does the following things:

1. Sends a request to the web service that starts compressing the database into a .zip file
2. Repeatedly invokes a web service function for checking whether the database has been compressed and is ready for download
3. Downloads the database using a NSURLSessionDownloadTask
4. Unzips the file and stores it into the documents directory
5. Renames the unzipped file into the desired name

Besides that, the entire process takes care of error handling to using callbacks i.e. closures.

The so far code is as follows:

```
func continueByRepeatedlyCheckingDatabaseZipReady() -> Void {
    let conditionClosure : ((x : String) -> Bool) = {x in x == "OK"}
    let repetitionClosure : ((x : String) -> String) = {result in String(result)}

    RequestTask(method: DatabaseZipReady()).apply(5, c: conditionClosure, f:repetitionClosure,
        onSuccess: {success in
            self.startDownloadDatabase()
        }, onFailure: {error in
            self.failure(error: error)
    })
} 

func startDownloadDatabase() -> Void {
    let databaseSourceURL : NSURL = RequestDatabaseURLForDownload().requestURL

    DownloadTask(url: databaseSourceURL,
        progressCallback: {received, total in

        }, successCallback: {location in
            self.unzippingDatabaseFile(location)
        }, failureCallback: {error in
            self.failure(error: error)
    }).resume()
}

func unzippingDatabaseFile(location : NSURL) {

    UnZip(sourceURL: location, destinationURL: FileManagement().documentsDirectory()).execute({
            self.renameDatabaseNameIntoCRMDB()
            self.deleteTemporalyDatabaseFileOnTheServer()
        }, onFailure: {error in
            self.failure(error: error)
    })
}
```

And so forth...

However, what I want to avoid (for the sake of code testability and simplicity) is having a pipeline of functions as such. As a first step, I've taken a look at GoF and tried to find a pattern that would suit this problem. But, unfortunately none of them do fit this problem.

Therefore, does anyone have a good piece of advice onto how to break out the dependencies between these functions i.e. the behaviour? Also keep in mind that I'm trying to have my code as functional as possible.

Comment: I think 1-3 should be just one (async) operation - for the rest simple functions seem fine and should be easily decoupled and testable (well of course it's one of those shitty-IO-testable things where you wonder if it really makes sense to test at all but you get it I think)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of observations.

1. You can remove the code that calls the next step in the process from these methods and change these methods to take completion handlers. Then, the code that calls these methods would then trigger the next step.

   ```
   func continueByRepeatedlyCheckingDatabaseZipReady(completionHandler: (Bool)->()) -> Void {
       let conditionClosure : ((x : String) -> Bool) = {x in x == "OK"}
       let repetitionClosure : ((x : String) -> String) = {result in String(result)}

       RequestTask(method: DatabaseZipReady()).apply(5, c: conditionClosure, f:repetitionClosure,
           onSuccess: {success in
               completionHandler(success)
           }, onFailure: {error in
               self.failure(error: error)
       })
   }

   func startDownloadDatabase(completionHandler: (NSURL)->()) -> Void {
       let databaseSourceURL : NSURL = RequestDatabaseURLForDownload().requestURL

       DownloadTask(url: databaseSourceURL,
           progressCallback: {received, total in

           }, successCallback: {location in
               completionHandler(location)
           }, failureCallback: {error in
               self.failure(error: error)
       }).resume()
   }

   func unzippingDatabaseFile(location : NSURL, completionHandler: ()->()) {
       UnZip(sourceURL: location, destinationURL: FileManagement().documentsDirectory()).execute({
               completionHandler()
           }, onFailure: {error in
               self.failure(error: error)
       })
   }
   ```

   By pulling the code that determines the next step, you can then unit test these methods without incurring the dependencies and without having to do any stubbing.
2. In terms of how to initiate the next step in the process, you can just call each in the completion handler of the prior one:

   ```
   func runWholeProcess() {
       continueByRepeatedlyCheckingDatabaseZipReady() { success in
           self.startDownloadDatabase() { location in
               self.unzippingDatabaseFile(location) {
                   self.renameDatabaseNameIntoCRMDB()
                   self.deleteTemporalyDatabaseFileOnTheServer()
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you don't like that nesting, there are lots of ways to establish dependencies between asynchronous tasks.

   - You can, for example, wrap them in asynchronous `NSOperation` subclass objects, and then you can use dependencies between them.
   - Or, if you're OK with third party libraries, you can use a promises/futures library (such as [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org/), [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures), or RXPromise) in which you can chain a series of asynchronous tasks together. I am conflicted on promises/futures in Swift: I like the idea, but I'm wary of these libraries due to the inconsistency between them, the lack of wide-spread acceptance of futures/promises in general in Swift, etc. But I mention it for the sake of completeness.

I must confess that I don't like relying on `self.failure` in these various methods, for a variety of reasons. I'd probably have my completion blocks called upon success or failure, passing along the relevant information, and retire `self.failure`. You want to make sure that these methods are not relying on any properties of the class, but rather just pass the relevant information that each requires from the other.